# Как найти программно созданный файл в android устройстве?

Tags: android

Необходимо вести запись в файл, последовательно добавляя символьные строки во внутреннюю память android-устройства. Реализация следующая:
В манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

В коде:

```
  public void writeLog(String mes) {
    try {
        File path=mContext.getFilesDir(); 
        File file = new File(path, "/" + FILENAME);
        PrintWriter pWriter= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        pWriter.println(getTime() + " " + mes);
        pWriter.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Util", "writeLog",e);
    }
}
```

Программа работает, по крайней мере исключений нет. Под отладчиком вижу, что запись выполняется в каталог /data/data/[имя моего проекта]/files/project.log. Открываю проводник на компьютере и не вижу даже каталога своего приложения. Есть  папка android/data/ - в ней папки приложений google. В ней нет вложенного каталога data. Как мне найти каталог своего приложения, чтобы убедиться, что файл создается и пишется? Если к этой папке так сложно получить доступ, как и куда мне писать во внутренней памяти, чтобы файл было легко найти, копировать и просматривать? SD-карты в устройстве не будет.

Comment: только с `root`-правами можно шариться по папкам `/data/data/`

Comment: Определите название вашего устройства, и погуглите `root <имя вашего устройства>`. На разных устройствах по-разному.

Comment: да инфы море, вбейте что то вроде `android получение root` и прочитайте, тот же `4pda` есть же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте заменить `mContext.getFilesDir()` на `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230629/getfilesdir-vs-environment-getdatadirectory) можно почитать обсуждение

Comment: Я попробовала. Запись выполняется в mnt/sdcard/Movies. Файл можно    легко найти и просмотреть. Но пока я подожду, может кто-то предложит лучший вариант.

Comment: а почему в movies? задайте название папки сами, типа Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/my-logs/" + file;

Comment: movies оказался тем каталогом, который виден и доступен из проводника, когда устройство подключено к компьютеру. Другие каталоги либо вообще не создаются, либо не видны из проводника.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно записывать в папку /sdcard/Android/.../files
Например:

```
...
File path = new File("/sdcard/Android/" + getPackageName() + "/files");
path.mkdirs();
File file = new File(path, "/" + FILENAME); //С этим файлом можно создавать потоки
...
```

Comment: каталог и файл создаются, однако если подключить планшет к компьютеру как обычный флэш-накопитель,  то каталог /sdcard недоступен. А мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь мог легко скопировать файл при необходимости и отправить разработчику.